# typing.Any in Python 3.9 and PEP 585 - Type Hinting Generics In Standard Collections

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, python-3.9

I am trying to understand if the `typing` package is still needed?

If in Python 3.8 I do:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict
my_dict = Dict[str, Any]
```

Now in Python 3.9 via PEP 585 it's now preferred to use the built in types for collections hence:

```py
from typing import Any
my_dict = dict[str, Any]
```

Do I still need to use the `typing.Any` or is there a built in type to replace it which I can not find?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The use of the `Any` remains the same. [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) applies only to standard collections.

> This PEP proposes to enable support for the generics syntax in all standard collections currently available in the `typing` module.

Starting with Python `3.9`, the following collections become `generic` and importing those from `typing` is deprecated:

- tuple # typing.Tuple
- list # typing.List
- dict # typing.Dict
- set # typing.Set
- frozenset # typing.FrozenSet
- type # typing.Type
- collections.deque
- collections.defaultdict
- collections.OrderedDict
- collections.Counter
- collections.ChainMap
- collections.abc.Awaitable
- collections.abc.Coroutine
- collections.abc.AsyncIterable
- collections.abc.AsyncIterator
- collections.abc.AsyncGenerator
- collections.abc.Iterable
- collections.abc.Iterator
- collections.abc.Generator
- collections.abc.Reversible
- collections.abc.Container
- collections.abc.Collection
- collections.abc.Callable
- collections.abc.Set # typing.AbstractSet
- collections.abc.MutableSet
- collections.abc.Mapping
- collections.abc.MutableMapping
- collections.abc.Sequence
- collections.abc.MutableSequence
- collections.abc.ByteString
- collections.abc.MappingView
- collections.abc.KeysView
- collections.abc.ItemsView
- collections.abc.ValuesView
- contextlib.AbstractContextManager # typing.ContextManager
- contextlib.AbstractAsyncContextManager # typing.AsyncContextManager
- re.Pattern # typing.Pattern, typing.re.Pattern
- re.Match # typing.Match, typing.re.Match

Comment: I thought that was the case, but just thought I would double check :)

Comment: `NoReturn`, `Union`, `Optional`, `Literal`, `ClassVar`, `Final`, `Annotated`, `Generic`, `TypeVar`, `AnyStr`, `Protocol`, `NewType`, `TypedDict`, `IO`, `TextIO`, `BinaryIO`, `Text`, `SupportsAbs`, `SupportsBytes `, `SupportsComplex`, `SupportsFloat`, `SupportsIndex`, `SupportsInt`, `SupportsRound` are other types that are also needed to be imported from the `typing` module besides `Any` in Python 3.9.

Comment: Ruff can fix this with the UP rule set.