# Python Any from typing vs generic any

Tags: python, generics, python-3.9

I know by PEP 585 on python 3.9 using generic types vs from the typing module is preferred as most types from typing will be deprecated. So does that also hold for the `Any` type?

I saw from this question: [typing.Any in Python 3.9 and PEP 585 - Type Hinting Generics In Standard Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65120501/typing-any-in-python-3-9-and-pep-585-type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collect)
that using `Any` from typing should still be fine under PEP 585. Then what is the difference from the `Any` from typing and the generic `any`?

It also seems like either way `any` should be implicit using the generic types for type hints. That I'm not too sure about either.

[Here in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types) it says that "In the following example, MyIterable is not generic but implicitly inherits from Iterable[Any]:" So does that mean using the generic Iterable in a type hint will implicitly mean `Iterable[any]`/`Iterable[Any]`?

So along with those questions in mind which of these would be the preferred way to do type hinting?

1:

```
from typing import Any
from collections.abc import Iterable

def some_function(data: list[Any], events: Iterable[Any]) -> None::
    ...
```

2:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def some_function(data: list, events: Iterable) -> None::
    ...
```

3:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def some_function(data: list[any], events: Iterable[any]) -> None:
    ...
```

Also a sidenote. I'd assume that if you're supporting versions 3.5-3.9 you'd always want to use the typing module for type hinting. I'm mostly looking at this for supporting only versions 3.9 and further.

Answer (score 9):

`any` has nothing to do with typing, and is not itself a type. It's a function that returns true when any element of its iterable argument is true.

```
>>> type(any)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> any([True, True])
True
>>> any([True, False])
True
>>> any([False, False])
False
```

So no, you cannot replace `typing.Any` with `any`. In fact, an attempt to do so will provide a tailor-made error message from `mypy`:

```
$ mypy <( echo "x: list[any] = [3]")
/dev/fd/63:1: error: Function "builtins.any" is not valid as a type
/dev/fd/63:1: note: Perhaps you meant "typing.Any" instead of "any"?
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

(Put another way, `typing.Any` *never* had anything to do with `any`, and the addition of `__class_getitem__` that made it possible to use `list` in place of `List` isn't applicable here.)

---

As far as the difference between `list` and `list[any]` (or `Iterable` and `Iterable[Any]`), I don't *think* there is any. Something of type `Iterable` could produce (an iterator that can produce) values of any type, just like the more explicit `Iterable[Any]`.

Comment: I only used the list for the concrete example. (I thought I had said "iterable" in the description, but it looks like I did not. Fixed.)

Comment: Alright that clears up the difference between `any` and `Any`. What about the part about just `Iterable` or `list`? Does that need the explicit `Any` or is it just implied by the lack of any other typing? The documentation I linked makes it sound like it isn't necessary and is implied.